# GUI Hangman issues

Tags: java, swing, methods

I'm working on a hangman in GUI, and I'm totally lost for what the issues are with my code. My Reset class won't run and I don't know what else to move on to so I can have a fully functioning game. Any help would be appreciated as I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

```java
package karce_jaidan_swinghangman;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class swinghangman2 {
    private static int numGuesses;
    private static ArrayList<Character> wrongGuesses = new ArrayList<>();
    private static char[] wordArr;
    private static String userinput;
    private static Dictionary dictionary;
    private static JTextField text = new JTextField();
    private static JTextArea console = new JTextArea();
    private static JTextArea repo = new JTextArea();
    private static String getuserinput, secretWord;
    private static final int MAX_GUESSES = 8;
    private static int key = 0;
    private static JPanel hangman = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel win = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel lost = new JPanel();

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public swinghangman2() throws FileNotFoundException {
//          FRAME
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1920, 1080);
        wrongGuesses.add('a');
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          WELCOME PANEL
        JPanel instructionscreen = new JPanel();
        instructionscreen.setLayout(null);
        instructionscreen.setSize(1920, 1080);
        instructionscreen.setVisible(false);

        // actual instructions on WELCOME PANEL
        JTextField helptext3 = new JTextField();
        helptext3.setText("How To Play: There will be a secret word that you need to guess. Every wrong letter is a body part on a stick figure. Complete the figure and you lose. Complete the figure and you lose. Press GUESSWORD if you want to guess the word, and HELP for these instructions at anytime.");
        helptext3.setBounds(100, 100, 1550, 100);
        helptext3.setEditable(false);
        // INSTRUCTIONS ON MIDGAME HELP SCREEN
        JTextField helptext4 = new JTextField();
        helptext4.setText("How To Play: There will be a secret word that you need to guess. Every wrong letter is a body part on a stick figure. Complete the figure and you lose. Complete the figure and you lose. Press GUESSWORD if you want to guess the word, and HELP for these instructions at anytime.");
        helptext4.setBounds(100, 100, 1550, 100);
        helptext4.setEditable(false);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          INSTRUCTION PANEL2 FOR MID GAME HELP
        JPanel instructionscreen2 = new JPanel();
        instructionscreen2.setLayout(null);
        instructionscreen2.setSize(1920, 1080);
        instructionscreen2.setVisible(false);

//          STARTGAME BUTTON ON WELCOME SCREEN
        JButton startGame = new JButton("Start Game");
        startGame.setBounds(900, 200, 200, 100);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // BUTTONS TO GET OUT OF INSTRUCTIONS
        JButton cont = new JButton("Continue");
        cont.setBounds(900, 600, 200, 100);
        JButton helpcont2 = new JButton("Continue");
        helpcont2.setBounds(900, 600, 200, 100);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          HANGMAN SWING  
        hangman.setSize(1920, 1080);
        hangman.setLayout(null);
        hangman.setVisible(false);
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setBounds(950, 500, 100, 100);
        hangman.add(exit);
        JButton exitgame = new JButton("Exit");
        exitgame.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

        JButton GuessLetter = new JButton("Guess Letter");
        GuessLetter.setBounds(1500, 700, 200, 60);
        hangman.add(GuessLetter);

        JButton GuessWord = new JButton("Guess Word");
        GuessWord.setBounds(1300, 700, 200, 60);
        hangman.add(GuessWord);

        JButton help = new JButton("Help");
        help.setBounds(1100, 700, 200, 60);
        hangman.add(help);

        JTextField console = new JTextField();
        console.setBounds(350, 10, 800, 650);
        console.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(console);
        scrollableTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollableTextArea.setBounds(350, 10, 800, 650);
        hangman.add(scrollableTextArea);

        repo.setText(secretWord);
        repo.setBounds(100, 500, 200, 100);
        repo.setEditable(false);

        // KEYBOARD---------------------------------------
        String[] qwertyRow1 = {"q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"};
        char[] qwertyRow1char = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'};
        String[] qwertyRow2 = {"a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",};
        char[] qwertyRow2char = {'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l',};
        String[] qwertyRow3 = {"z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m",};
        char[] qwertyRow3char = {'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm',};

        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(50, 675, 800, 50);
        tf1.setEditable(false);
        hangman.setLayout(null);
        hangman.add(tf1);
        hangman.setSize(3000, 3000);
        for (int i = 0; i < qwertyRow1.length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int xaxis = i * 100;
            JButton b = new JButton(qwertyRow1[i]);
            b.setBounds(xaxis, 750, 50, 50); // sets bounds, !!!
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tf1.setText(tf1.getText() + qwertyRow1[x]);
                }
            });
            hangman.add(b);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < qwertyRow2.length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int xaxis = i * 100;
            JButton b = new JButton(qwertyRow2[i]);
            b.setBounds(xaxis, 825, 50, 50); // sets bounds, !!!
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tf1.setText(tf1.getText() + qwertyRow2[x]);
                }
            });
            hangman.add(b);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < qwertyRow3.length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int xaxis = i * 100;
            JButton b = new JButton(qwertyRow3[i]);
            b.setBounds(xaxis, 900, 50, 50); // sets bounds, !!!
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tf1.setText(tf1.getText() + qwertyRow3[x]);
                }
            });
            hangman.add(b);
        }
        JButton delete = new JButton("BACKSPACE");
        delete.setBounds(700, 900, 150, 50);
        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (tf1.getText().length() > 0) {
                    tf1.setText(tf1.getText().substring(0, tf1.getText().length() - 1));
                }
            }
        });
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      ENDGAME
        lost.setSize(1920, 1040);
        lost.setLayout(null);
        lost.setVisible(false);
        win.setSize(1920, 1040);
        win.setLayout(null);
        win.setVisible(false);

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          ACTIONLISTENERS
        helpcont2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                instructionscreen2.setVisible(false);
                hangman.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        cont.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("aa");
                hangman.setVisible(true);
                instructionscreen.setVisible(false);
                main();
            }
        });
        help.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                instructionscreen2.setVisible(true);
                hangman.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        exitgame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        GuessWord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (validWordGuess() == true) {
                    checkWordGuess();
                    displayData();
                    text.setText("");
                    complete();
                }
            }
        });
        GuessLetter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (validLetteruserinput() == true) {
                    checkLetterGuess();
                    displayData();
                    text.setText("");
                    complete();
                }
            }
        });

        // ADDITIONS
        instructionscreen2.add(helptext4);
        instructionscreen.add(helptext3);
        instructionscreen.add(exit);
        instructionscreen.add(cont);
        instructionscreen2.add(helpcont2);
        hangman.add(exitgame);
        hangman.add(repo);
        f.add(instructionscreen);
        f.add(instructionscreen2);
        f.add(hangman);
        f.add(lost);
        f.add(win);

        // VISIBILITY
        instructionscreen.setVisible(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          HANGMAN METHODS
    private static void reset() {
        numGuesses = 0;
        wrongGuesses.clear();
        secretWord = Dictionary.getRandomWord();
        int Length = secretWord.length();
        wordArr = new char[Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            wordArr[i] = '_';
        }
        console.setText("aaa");
    }

    private static void main() {
        reset();
    }

    private static boolean validLetteruserinput() {
        userinput = (text.getText());
        if (userinput.length() == 1 && userinput.toLowerCase() == userinput) // could be issue later
                                                                             // if no work
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean validWordGuess() {
        userinput = (text.getText());
        boolean check = false;
        if (userinput.length() == secretWord.length()) {
            check = true;
        }
        else {
            repo.setText(repo.getText() + "\n" + "Invalid Input.");
        }
        text.setText("");
        return check;
    }

    private static void checkLetterGuess() {
        int temp = 0;
        char letter = userinput.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            if (letter == (secretWord.charAt(i))) {
                wordArr[i] = letter;
            }
            else if (wordArr[i] != '_') {
                repo.setText(repo.getText() + "\n" + "You've already guessed this");
            }
            else {
                temp++;
            }
        }
        if (temp == secretWord.length()) {
            wrongGuesses.add(letter);
            numGuesses++;
        }
    }

    private static void checkWordGuess() {
        boolean won = true;
        while (won) {
            if (userinput.equals(secretWord)) {
                win.setVisible(true);
                hangman.setVisible(false);
                won = false;
            }
            else if (!userinput.equals("cancel") && !userinput.equals(secretWord)) {
                repo.setText(repo.getText() + " Wrong.");
                numGuesses++;
                won = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void displayData() {
        drawPerson(numGuesses);
        repo.setText(secretWord);
        console.setText(console.getText() + ("\n"));
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            console.setText(console.getText() + (wordArr[i] + " "));
        }
        console.setText(console.getText() + "\n" + ("Wrong Guesses:" + wrongGuesses));
        console.setText(console.getText() + "\n"
                + ("You have " + (MAX_GUESSES - numGuesses) + " guesses left."));
    }

    private static boolean wordCompleted() {
        // TODO: Replace with your own code
        boolean correct = false;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            if (wordArr[i] == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        if (counter == secretWord.length()) {
            correct = true;
        }
        return correct;
    }

    private static void complete() {
        if (MAX_GUESSES - numGuesses == 0) {
            lost.setVisible(true);
            hangman.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (wordCompleted() == true) {
            win.setVisible(true);
            hangman.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private static void drawPerson(int numGuesses) {
        Scanner draw = null;
        try {
            draw = new Scanner(new File("man" + numGuesses));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file to draw display.");
        }
        while (draw.hasNextLine()) {
            console.setText(console.getText() + "\n" + (draw.nextLine()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new swinghangman2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your import statements look fine.  The rest of your code is a total mess.  Static fields are not helpful.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for **java swing hangman** in order to see how other people have done it?